# Rotating AppBar MenuItem Icons only

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Please excuse me if this question has been asked before (I couldn't find it).

I don't think that I'm the first one trying this, but I'me fairly new to Android Dev:

I've got a **support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity** with Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar set as style.

I need to support APIs 19 to 23.

What I'm trying to accomplish is keeping the UI orientation fixed while rotating the MenuItem **icons(!)** according to the device orientation.

I have a menu defined like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_help"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Help"/>
</menu>
```

I didn't find a way to access the Views in which the Icon Drawables are drawn, so I cannot animate them.
I tried inflating ActionViews which were just ImageViews with the same drawables as src but displaying the ActionViews I didn't manage displaying them in the same style as the icons (size, position, padding, etc...). Instead they were displayed way to large and instead of the title and so on.

I spent some time looking for the Styles used for the ActionViews in the SupportActionBar or a view to specify my own LayoutParams but I couldn't find a solution this way.

**What I need is two Views in place of the MenuItems inside the AppBar that I can click and animate upon device orientation changes.**

I'd really appreciate your help as I've already wasted a lot of time on this.